# elastic search: split result in aggregation sub queries (top hits aggregation searches)?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have elastic search document with field "user" and we have built following query to fetch 1 document of ["user"=  "kimchy"] and 1 document of ["user" = "elasticsearch"].

```
GET /_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "user": ["kimchy","elasticsearch"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sample": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's one more field in these documents named as "goals" which has integer value. We want to get:

1. 1 document of ["user"=  "kimchy"] with goal>10.
2. 1 document of ["user"=  "kimchy"] with goal<=10
3. 1 document of ["user" = "elasticsearch"] with goal>10
4. 1 document of ["user" = "elasticsearch"] with goal<=10

One way is to execute this query twice with multi search with first for goal>10 and second for goal<=10. Is there any better way to do this?